# Redirect to another page from DisplayAlert Popup Xamarin.Form

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey Everyone I am using Autofac(MVVM) my problem is how to redirect to another page from DisplayAlert Popup by clicking ok button in popup screen? As the display alert is in my Views and in my ViewModels the ICommand navigate to another page is navigator.

```
         PushAsync<PageViewModel>();
```

Some of my Code snip:

ViewModels

```
   public class HomePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
    private readonly INavigator _navigator;

    public HomePageViewModel(INavigator navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
        CmdInvites = new Command(Cmdinvites);
    }

    public ICommand CmdInvites { get; private set; }


    //Invite PhoneBook
    private void Cmdinvites()
    {
        _navigator.PushAsync<PhoneContactViewModel>();
    }

  }


 zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
 // Stop analysis until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
     zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
     // Show an alert
     await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
     // Navigate away
     await Navigation.PopAsync();
      <-------------this is where i want to redirect the {Binding CmdInvites}           
 });
```

Thank you for the time reading my post.

Comment: Just push to the navigation stack. What is the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to Navigate away from the Scan Page? Once scanning is done.

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan exactly thats what Im trying to do, After Scanning navigate away to another page.

Comment: @jaketalledo would it be possible for you to upload your code in Github?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another *DisplayAlert* method constructor which will be like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
 // Stop analysis until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
     zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
     // Show an alert
     if(await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "Accept","Cancel"))
     {
     // Navigate away
     await Navigation.PopAsync();
      <-------------this is where i want to redirect the {Binding CmdInvites}
     }      
 });
```

Comment: when i debug my error is could not resolve type _inavigator.pushasync<viewMode>(); I already register it to containerbuilder

Comment: This is something else then, and its basically pointing that happening because of not register something. see what are you missing e.g IViewModel, INavigationServce etc.